# jQuery Table Libraries

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

What are some good jQuery table libraries (in the same vein as [TableSorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)). As a bare minimum I'm looking for the ability to sort tables row based on their type. Handy functions would automatic JSON handling, and predefined ajax handles.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/). It has worked out great with my ASP.NET MVC application.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few out there, have a look on [JQuery Rain](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?s=table), It lists a number of them.

Answer (score 0):

A great alternative to Datatables is  dynatable.com, handsontable.com.

Try out